# Implementing Poison Pill messaging pattern with RabbitMQ consumers

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging

Java & RabbitMQ here. I need to implement sort of a *poison pill* pattern where, upon handling a particular message, the consumer needs to cancel itself and stop receiving/handling any further messages. Full stop and clean up. The message kills the consumer and releases the thread, memory, etc.

I see consumers have a `handleCancel` method that they can implement to respond to cancellation commands from the outside, but how do I handle a poison pill message inside a consumer that tells the consumer to fall over dead?

Comment: Why the CV? Its absolutely on topic (this is solved via programming), is **not** a duplicate, shows research and is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think RabbitMQ handles this scenario for some reason.

My solution which appears to be working:

1. Implement a stateful consumer that exists in one of two states: `Processing` (default) and `Terminating`
2. When its in the `Processing` state it consumes and handles messages off the queue like normal. When it receives the magical poison pill (perhaps a value in the message header/properties, or maybe a specific value in the message itself) it sets its status to `Terminating` and does not process the message. It also uses an async event bus to send a custom `ShutdownConsumerEvent` to an external handler. This event is instantiated with both the `channel` and `consumerTag` sent to the consumer (e.g. `ShutdownConsumerEvent event = new ShutdownConsumerEvent(channel, consumerTag);`)
3. Any more messages the consumer receives while in the `Terminating` state get republished to the queue, with ACKs enabled so we don't lose them and have pseudo-transactionality
4. When the external `ShutdownConsumerSubscriber` (a registered handler to receive `ShutdownConsumerEvents`) receives the command to shut down the consumer, it does this by issuing a `channel.basicCancel(consumerTag)`